# Regular expression that matches n numeric characters, along with 1 or 2 non-numeric characters

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I've been using a standard `([0-9]+)` pattern to match numbers in a string, but have a strange edge case now. I want to match the following:

123
456
.123
123.
%123
31st
14th
2nd
100.55
555.10

In the above cases, the non-numeric characters are:
.
%
s
h
n
d

But they could be a variety of characters.
Thoughts?

JS or PHP would be great.

Comment: is it `%123`? Normally percentages are `123%`, and as that seems to be the only exception it seems a bit odd.

Comment: I suppose I should add: you should only use regular expressions when you have a well defined string pattern that you want to match. At this point, you haven't provided enough information to accurately determine the pattern that will match what you're after.

Comment: Also, it's important to tag what language you'll be using the regular expression with. Perl uses different syntax than PHP uses different syntax than JavaScript uses different syntax than C#...

Comment: Thanks for the questions zzzzBov. You're right: I should've specified the language. JS or PHP would be great. I could supply some more examples, but the crux of it is that the string would be a number other than when it leads or trails with 1 or 2 non-numeric characters.

Comment: Ok, so what *doesn't* match? Is `%30.20rd` valid? how about `@#1aa`? What about simply `4o`? You need to be able to specify exactly what pass conditions are needed, and exactly what failure conditions are needed. Otherwise, you should avoid Regular Expressions.

Comment: You make really good points. I'm going to do some more research about the exact patterns I'm looking for and come back to this question with more specifics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to create several rules for all cases :

```
(\d+(?:\.\d*)?)        // 123 ; 123. ; 123.45
([%.]\d+)              // %123 ; .123
(\d+(?:st|nd|th))      // 31st ; 2nd ; 14th
```

Then mixed :

```
((?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?)|(?:[%.]\d+)|(?:\d+(?:st|nd|th)))
```

If you want something shorter, you can simply use `([%.\dshnd]+)`, but this will catch many non-wanted entries, like `%%123%%`.

Comment: This is making me question exactly what I'm trying to achieve, and if it's possible without missing out on some other edge-edge cases. I'll come back to it shortly with a more refined description of what I need. Thanks for the post. I'll test it out in the meantime.

Comment: Note - do not need to escape `.` and `%` inside character classes.

Comment: Thanks zessx. This gets me close.

Answer (score 3):

Start with a pattern that gets you what you want:

```
\d+
```

Now you also want to match decimal numbers, so expand your options:

this one matches numbers followed by an optional decimal point

```
\d+\.?
```

this one matches decimal numbers:

```
\d*\.\d+
```

joining both will give you a solid number matching pattern (this may still have issues if you don't want to match numbers like `000.0000`):

```
(?:\d+\.?|\d*\.\d+)
```

Now comes the tricky part. You need to determine *exactly* what other characters may be prefix or suffix the number.

Given the example, I will make the following assumptions:

- `%` may prefix a decimal, but without a suffix
- `st`, `nd`, `rd`, and `th` may suffix only whole numbers

Given these assumptions:

`%` characters can be optionally matched on decimals:

```
(?:%?(?:\d+\.?|\d*\.\d+))
```

whole numbers with suffixes can be matched with (this does not validate the suffixes, `1nd` would be valid):

```
(?:\d+(?:st|nd|rd|th)
```

Joining these two patterns produces:

```
(?:(?:%?(?:\d+\.?|\d*\.\d+))|(?:\d+(?:st|nd|rd|th)))
```

Of course, you'll probably want to restrict the match to the entire string:

```
/^(?:(?:%?(?:\d+\.?|\d*\.\d+))|(?:\d+(?:st|nd|rd|th)))$/
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for validation of patterns  you expect (like dates?) you can do this:

```
[\d.%]*(nd|st|th){0,1}
```

If you know the position of the % is leading, or that you only have a single decimal or that if a decimal you don't want st/nd/etc you can refine like this:

```
([%]){0,1}[\d]*((((\.[\d]+){0,1}){0,1})|((nd|st|th|rd){0,1}))
```

I am still not handling a space anywhere but I think you can see how you might add that in? Further you may want to ensure that 1st versus 11th, etc - if you are worried about improving the validation further can start to go to something like for the date (you maybe able to google better):

```
([023]){0,1}1st|([02]){0,1}2nd|([02]){0,1}3rd|(11|12|13|30|(([012]){0,1}(([4-9])|0))th)
```

Some extra brackets there to try and make as clear as possible

Answer (score 1):

This one suits your needs:

```
^([.]|%)?\d+(((?<=^1)|(?<!^1)1)st|(?<!^1)((?<=^2)|2)nd|(?<!^1)((?<=^3)|3)rd|th|[.]\d*)?$
```

[Demo](http://regexr.com?33mo5)

```
^                            # start of the string
([.]|%)?                     # . or % {0 or 1 time}
\d+                          # any digit {1 or more times}
(
    ((?<=^1)|(?<!^1)1)st     # either (1) or (ending with 1 but not 11) followed by st
    |(?<!^1)((?<=^2)|2)nd    # either (2) or (ending with 2 but not 12) followed by nd
    |(?<!^1)((?<=^3)|3)rd    # either (3) or (ending with 3 but not 13) followed by rd
    |th                      # th
    |[.]\d*                  # . followed by (a digit {0 or more times})
)?                           # {0 or 1 time}
$                            # end of the string
```

Note that JS won't be able to understand this regexp since it doesn't support lookbehinds (`?<=` and `?<!`).